# SharpSVN.DLL - C#.NET- Get SVN Repository in windows application

Tags: c#, svn

How can I access the SVN repository using SharpSVN and allow the user to select the project from a windows form.

Answer (score 5):

SharpSVN is used by [SVNMonitor](http://www.svnmonitor.com/) tool.
Now that [SVNMonitor](http://www.svnmonitor.com/) is open source, makes sense to take a look at its trunk to see how it’s implemented.
It's at 
http://sharpregion.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/svnmonitor/trunk/

Some of the code from SVNMonitor using SharpSVN

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using SharpSvn;
using System.Net;
using SVNMonitor.Entities;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SVNMonitor.View.Dialogs;
using SVNMonitor.Helpers;

namespace SVNMonitor.SVN
{
    internal class SharpSVNClient
    {
        #region Fields

        private const string RecommendProperty = "svnmonitor:recommend";

        #endregion Fields

        #region Methods

        private static SvnClient GetSvnClient()
        {
            SvnClient client = new SvnClient();

            return client;
        }

        private static SvnClient GetSvnClient(Source source)
        {
            SvnClient client = GetSvnClient();

            SetAuthentication(client, source);

            return client;
        }

        private static void SetAuthentication(SvnClient client, Source source)
        {
            if (source.Authenticate)
            {
                SetAuthentication(client, source.UserName, source.Password);
            }
            else
            {
                SharpSvn.UI.SvnUI.Bind(client, (IWin32Window)null);
            }
        }
```

More at http://sharpregion.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/svnmonitor/trunk/SVNMonitor/SVN/SharpSVNClient.cs

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this.

Biju Joseph